# Adding 127.0.0.1 to hosts file to redirect locally has error. Says my site “refused to connect.”

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, https, hosts

**I answered this below for anyone that is interested**

I'm on Windows 10 using Chrome, Firefox and MS Edge. I'm trying to do something for a class I'm taking and can't get it to work. All I want to do is add something like this to the hosts file:

127.0.0.1 mysite.dev

This is ALL to run on my local PC. I eventually need to have my site able to run on IIS, but this is the first step and I can't get past it. (I'm on my second day trying)

What I've done:

1. I did edits in notepad on a file on my desktop.
2. I renamed the original hosts file in the drivers/etc directory.
3. I copied my file into the drivers/etc directory.
4. I ran ipconfig -flushdns
5. I successfully pinged the new site with: ping mysite.dev
6. I cleared browsing history in all three browsers.
7. I reopened all three browsers.

All that failed to make any difference (and I rebooted as well) So I added this:

1. I ran ipconfig -flushdns
2. Then ipconfig -renew
3. Then ipconfig -registerdns

Then repeated steps 5->6 and all failed to make any difference. These are the errors per browser:

Chrome: This site can’t be reached mysite.dev refused to connect.

Firefox: Unable to connect Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at www.mysite.dev.

MS Edge: Hmmm...can’t reach this page

I noticed that all three browsers changed http to https. Not sure if that mattered but I followed instructions to disable this re-direct for all three browsers and NONE of them actually stopped the redirect to https.

And I still can't the correct result, which should be the IIS default page. I can see the IIS default page with localhost, so IIS is running.

Help! Any ideas or directions at all would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Got the answer from someone. Google owns the .dev domains and has restrictions on it so it HAS to be HTTPS, which requires certs etc, which is not in the scope of my class. I just changed it to mysite.local and BOOM!, there it was! Thanks.